# My java program will not return the correct value?

Tags: java

I have written a java program that finds the recursive sum of the digits of a number.

It prints the correct value in the line right before the return statement, but still returns the wrong value.

```
public class DRoot {
  public static int digital_root(int n) {
    //going to solve using recursion
    System.out.println(n + " before if and for loop");
    String temporary = Integer.toString(n);
    int tempInteger = n;
    System.out.println(temporary.length() + " is temporary length");
    if(temporary.length() == 1){
      System.out.println("returns at beginning");
      System.out.println("n before return is: " + n);
      return tempInteger;
    }
    n = 0;
    if(temporary.length() != 1){
      for(int i = 0; i < temporary.length(); i ++){
        n += Integer.parseInt(temporary.substring(i, i+1));
        System.out.println(n + " during if and for loop");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("returns after for loop");
      return n;
    }
    //calls the digital_root method recursively
    digital_root(n);
    return n;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your last call to digital_root(n) , you don't set "n" variable with the method result ;

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. I see you haven't yet taken the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There's a link to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) at the bottom of that page. The help center has lots of useful links, including [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Your code could have been much shorter and simpler.

Based on your attempts, perhaps it would be best to represent the number as a `String`.

At each step of the recursion, take the first digit and add it to the sum of the remaining sub-string. Once you run out of digits, you stop.

Something like this:

```
public class DRoot {
    public static int recursiveDigitSum(String n) {
        if (n.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return n.charAt(0) - '0' + recursiveDigitSum(n.substring(1));
    }

    public static int digital_root(int n) {
        return recursiveDigitSum(n + "");
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(digital_root(51)); // outputs 6
    }
}
```

The updated answer keeps your original method signature.